# Clock since daylight saving time began, wrong by an hour and a half

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

Since daylight saving time kicked in a couple of days ago my consecutive days haven't been updating till 1:30 am. They always used to update after midnight.is this a bug and is it going to be fixed?  Have other people noticed too?

Comment: Stack Overflow is on UTC; so it just so happens that the time is an exact match for you when on Standard time. It won't be when in DST.

Comment: This would only explain an hour difference at best besides my kindle is on utc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other commented - Stack Overflow (and the Stack Exchange network) uses UTC internally.

Since UTC is not subject to DST, when people move in and out of DST, they will see the changeover drift accordingly.

Comment: -1 is 'Merica time not good enough for you elitists...

Comment: @AdamRackis - Oy. The HQ is in NYC, you know?

Comment: I did know that - was just joking.

Comment: @AdamRackis - Yeah, I kinda got that ;)

Comment: I never know around here :)